# How do I run an application on my phone from my PC?

Tags: applications, usb

I have a phone with a touch-screen malfunction, I want to run applications on it from my computer, connected by USB. Is that possible?

I've tried applications like http://mymobiler.com, but that has failed me (I can see the screen, it's not responsive).

Sadly, I have ADB turned off, so I cannot use applications like the android screencast, or DroidExplorer.

Comment: Can you not reboot the device up in a recovery mode that doesn't require the touch interface?

Comment: What exact phone model is it? If it is some of the hackable ones (Samsung, Sony, HTC) you could enable adb via some other means like fastboot or flashing a custom recovery or firmware that has adb enabled.

Comment: HTC HD2, and I managed to activate ADB, so thanks for the help :D

Answer (score -2):

LogMeIn Ignition may work for what you want to do. It really remote controls the pc but to truly run a PC app it would have to be on a PC.

Comment: I don't want to run an app on the PC, I want to run an app on the phone, **from** the PC.

Answer (score -2):

If you are a developer, you can install apps directly from your PC by accessing and enabling:

```
Settings → Applications → Development → USB Debugging option.
```

Comment: Have you read the question? ADB is off, and I am without a touch screen. I cannot activate it. Also, I want to RUN and application, not INSTALL it.